# How to reset seachDisplayController View to original state programatically

Tags: objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchbardelegate

I have the UISearchDisplayController page view as follows (original state)

[image]

After clicking on the searchbar and typing some search term, I get a list of results in the table

[image]

After clicking on an entry in the table, a new viewController is displayed on top of the stack

[image]

My intention is that on the click of the cancel button (on top left), the root view will display the original state of the searchDisplay controller

[image]

This is what I have tried

In my cancel method (triggered when I click on the top left hand cancel button)

```
- (void)cancel
{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
  [self searchBarCancelButtonClicked:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar];
}
```

And in the searchbar delegate method I did this

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;

    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    self.searchBar.text = @"";
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = YES;
    [self searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:self.searchDisplayController];
}
```

All I manage to achieve after clicking on the cancel button is this

[image]

The original tableview seems to be missing (appears only if I click on the page)

How can I modify my methods to revert the search to its' original state?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `[searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:NO]`

This should hide the search table.